# How do I make Atom-editor background transparency in Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: css, less, atom-editor, transparency

Here is my styles.less code(which is basically almost nothing)

```
// style the background color of the tree view
.tree-view {
  // background-color: whitesmoke;
}

// style the background and foreground colors on the atom-text-editor-element itself
atom-text-editor {
  // color: white;
  // background-color: hsl(180, 24%, 12%);
}
// style UI elements inside atom-text-editor
atom-text-editor .cursor {
  // border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: `background-color: transparent;`

Comment: @AmanSharma It didn't work , it looks still the same

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the Window transparency using CSS, but there are packages that add that functionality e.g. [atom-transparency](https://github.com/transcranial/atom-transparency)